# ASP.NET custom user control cannot access sitemap

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, sitemap

I have a footer that I am adding to a masterpage. Within this footer, if constructs menus based on the Current Node of the sitemap, however the sitemap is coming back as null. Does anyone know how to fix this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Show us which code you are using to get the sitemap / current node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out last night. I just grabbed the SiteMap root node from the Master Page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Page.Master.FindControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx)

```
this.Page.Master.FindControl("SiteMapID1");
```